# Height of RMarkdown code chunk in reveal.js slides

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, reveal.js

I keep running into the problem of my code chunks overflowing in my slides, and so having to scroll around them. Not optimal for teaching.

1. How can one make a code chunk taller (or wider) on a chunk by chunk basis?
2. How can one in reveal.js or other html formats change code text size, again, on a chunk by chunk basis. I know globally I can change things in the CSS, but want to be more dynamic than that.

p.s. If anyone wants to know how to change the center-text behavior while not affecting other slide elements, troubleshot that one recently, and it's nontrivial, but doable.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope this suits your needs.

Answer (score 4):

### Customize Code Chunks using CSS

You could use `fenced_code_attributes` to add a CSS class (or several different classes) to certain code chunks. For this to work, you add this option to your YAML header and define a new hook using `knit_hoooks$set()` (for details see [Hooks](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/)). After that, we can use the chunk option `class = 'myCssClass'`.

In the following example we define a class `.smallCode`, which sets a certain width for the chunk and a smaller font size. In the final document, the result looks like this:

```
<pre class="sourceCode r smallCode">
  <code class="sourceCode r">
  THE CODE WE PRODUCED
  </code>
</pre>
```

As you can see, we just added the class `smallCode` to the `<pre>` element! Yay!

You can modify anything, the font styles, the background and much more. For an overview of possibilities check out this [CSS Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)

### Wrapping Source Code

If you want the source code to be wrapped, you can use the chunk option `tidy=T` with its option `width.cutoff` (also implemented in the example below).

### Reproducible Example:

````
---
title: "Customized Code Chunks"
author: Martin Schmelzer
date: March 22, 2005
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    md_extensions: +fenced_code_attributes
---
<style>
pre.smallCode {
  width:  360px;               /* Change the width of the chunk */
  height: 360px;               /* Change the height of the chunk */
  font-size: 0.4em;            /* Change the font-size */
  background-color: lightgrey; /* Change background color */
} 
</style>

```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  return(paste0(
    "```{.r",
    ifelse(is.null(options$class),
      "", 
      paste0(" .", gsub(" ", " .", options$class))
    ),
    "}\n",
    x,
    "\n```"
  ))
})
```

# Customized Code Chunks

## Example

<!-- Here we use the option tidy=TRUE with a cutoff after 40 characters -->
```{r, class = 'smallCode', tidy=T, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=40)}
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20))
```
````

---

**And here is a screenshot of the code chunk we just have customized:**

[image]

Comment: The height is adjusted automatically in this example. For 200px use `height: 200px;` in the CSS block.

Comment: Changed the answer. Now I also altered the chunks height.

Comment: Huh - yes, if I put the style in the .Rmd. No if I put the styling in my styles.css file. Weird....